# How to differentiate new added objects and updated objects in DirSync search results (Active Directory)?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, activedirectorymembership, active-directory-group

Both new **added** objects and **updated** objects are returned in DirSync search results, from Active Directory server.

**How to differentiate them**, in **SearchResponse**?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchresponse.aspx

As we know, if an AD objects has been deleted, its attribute 'isDeleted' is marked as TRUE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. Can't you use whenChanged, whenCreated, usnChanged usnCreated attributes to do what you need ?

Comment: Does AD support modifyTimestamp and createTimestamp?

Comment: Yes as far as I understand 'modifyTimestamp' is 'whenChanged' and 'createTimestamp' is whenCreated. 'whenChanged' and 'whenCreated' are both 'operational attribute' like 'modifyTimestamp' and 'createTimestamp'. It also exists 'usnChanged' and 'usnCreated' where 'usn' stands for Uniq Sequence Number.

Comment: The attribute "whenChanged" is not returned in search result when using DirSync control. Because - http://www.ms-news.net/f2378/possible-to-include-ad-whenchanged-attribute-in-an-attribute-flow-5118231.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can. You may need to cache all of the objectGuids locally and do a lookup to see if the objectGuid is one you don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

DirectorySearcher will only return attributes that have changed. WhenCreated is only changed when an object is created, so if it has a value then you're looking at a new object, otherwise it's an update.